# Seleccionar el último registro de cada uno de los usuarios

Tags: sql, sql-server

necesitaría conseguir con una consulta el último registro de cada unos de los usuarios que han iniciado o cerrado sesión de la siguiente tabla:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Con esta cosulta:

```
SELECT         sysIdTrace, sysAplicacion, sysProcessName, sysTraceDescription, sysStatus, sysTraceTime, sysUsuario, sysUserName, sysHostName, sysUserGuid
FROM            lsysTrace as P
WHERE        (sysProcessName = 'Log de sesión') AND (sysTraceTime = (SELECT MAX(sysTraceTime)from lsysTrace where 
                            sysUserName = p.sysUserName AND sysUsuario>0 AND sysTraceDescription like'%ha iniciado%') OR sysTraceTime = (SELECT MAX(sysTraceTime)from lsysTrace where 
                            sysUserName = p.sysUserName AND sysUsuario>0 AND sysTraceDescription like'%ha finalizado%'))
```

Parece que el resultado es el correcto, pero es extremadamente lenta, ya que es una tabla que como sospecharéis, puede contener miles de registros, por lo que es obvio que no estoy escribiendo bien la consulta.
Alguien me puede echar una mano, por favor?
Muchas gracias.

Comment: Para ayudarte mejor podrías agregar el script de la tabla con datos  para poder hacer pruebas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Crearía un índice en las columnas sysUserName y sysTraceTime. Esto va a permitir que la BBDD encuentre y recupere rápidamente las filas que coincidan con las condiciones del WHERE.

Así:

```
CREATE INDEX idx_sysTrace ON lsysTrace (sysUserName, sysTraceTime);

SELECT sysIdTrace, sysAplicacion, sysProcessName, sysTraceDescription, sysStatus, sysTraceTime, sysUsuario, sysUserName, sysHostName, sysUserGuid
FROM lsysTrace as P
WHERE (sysProcessName = 'Log de sesión')
AND (sysTraceTime = (SELECT MAX(sysTraceTime) from lsysTrace where sysUserName = p.sysUserName AND sysUsuario > 0 AND sysTraceDescription like '%ha iniciado%')
    OR sysTraceTime = (SELECT MAX(sysTraceTime) from lsysTrace where sysUserName = p.sysUserName AND sysUsuario > 0 AND sysTraceDescription like '%ha finalizado%'))
```

Otra forma de que sea más rápida es evitar el uso de subquerys y, usar un solo JOIN para combinar los resultados de ambos SELECT.

Así:

```
SELECT P.sysIdTrace, P.sysAplicacion, P.sysProcessName, P.sysTraceDescription, P.sysStatus, P.sysTraceTime, P.sysUsuario, P.sysUserName, P.sysHostName, P.sysUserGuid
FROM lsysTrace as P
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT sysUserName, MAX(sysTraceTime) as max_time
    FROM lsysTrace
    WHERE sysUsuario > 0 AND (sysTraceDescription like '%ha iniciado%' OR sysTraceDescription like '%ha finalizado%')
    GROUP BY sysUserName
) as T ON P.sysUserName = T.sysUserName AND P.sysTraceTime = T.max_time
WHERE P.sysProcessName = 'Log de sesión'
```